# How can I make an iframe seo friendly?

Tags: javascript, iframe, seo

I have a website which provides embeddable content in an iframe. I want search engines to see it so the site gets backlinks. To that end I'm planning to replace the content with a link to our site and a javascript button that changes the content back to the iframe. That way the pages using our widget load quicker as well. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Easy: ditch them... :P

Answer (score 4):

You can index your iFrame trough robots.txt and google web master tools (add the URL of the iframe source to be crawled). This will only index the static page withouth the page around it. So it won't score high on the Search Engine Result page (as it misses too much, navigation usability).

Since Google Penguin 2.0, links in iFrames might be treated differently as well.

I suggest not using the iFrame if you aim for Search Engine Purposes, this will probably affect your search engine score more negatively than positivly

Answer (score 3):

Links In IFrames Pass Value In Google
http://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html

Confirmed: Google Passed Value From An Iframed Link
http://www.highrankings.com/forum/index.php/topic/46890-confirmed-google-passed-value-from-an-iframed-link/

Answer (score 1):

change `<iframe></iframe>` to `<object></object>`

change `src` to `data`

example :

```
<object data="http://example.com/" title="My Title" width="640" height="270" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;"></object>
```

Comment: I don't think search engines will recognize this either.

Comment: yes, this is an alternative way to not reduce the value of your seo score. Sorry for my poor english :)

Answer (score 0):

To make SEO friendly, avoid using IFRAME, as contents in IFRAME will NOT be indexed.

Reference: http://moz.com/community/q/iframes-seo

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't post more then 2 links yet

> a javascript button that changes the content

this you will need to test see what Matt Cutts has to say on the topic http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mibrj2bOFCU